# Subtitles not synchronizing on Samsung Tizen SmartTV

Tags: javascript, synchronization, tizen, samsung-smart-tv, subtitle

I am trying to sync the subtitles with a video on a Samsung Tizen TV angularjs app.

I turn on my external subtitles with this function.

```
var downloadRequest = new tizen.DownloadRequest('http://example.com/subtitles.srt', "wgt-private-tmp");
tizen.download.start(downloadRequest, {

    oncompleted: function(downloadId, fullPath) {
        webapis.avplay.setExternalSubtitlePath(fullPath);
    },

    onfailed: function(error) {
        console.log('Failed to download Subtitle');
    }
});
```

Everything is working.

The sync problem occurs when I am moving forward or backward in the video. I'm trying to sync it with `webapis.avplay.setSubtitlePosition(webapis.avplay.getCurrentTime())` function, but the subtitles start from beginning.